# Unable to get value of drop down in typescript angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to get dropdown option value into my app.component.ts file from html, i receive all the input value but unable to get the dropdown value into typescript file.

My search.component.html file:

```
 <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="registerYourself()">
    <select class="wide" id="countrycode" formControlName="countryCode">
        <option *ngFor="let code of countryCodes" [ngValue]="code.value">{{ code.title }}</option>
    </select>
    <select class="wide" id="box" formControlName="category">
        <option *ngFor="let cat of vendorType" [ngValue]="cat.value">{{ cat.title }}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
</form>
```

My search.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-vendor-form',
  templateUrl: './vendor-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vendor-form.component.css']
})


export class VendorFormComponent implements OnInit {
  vendorType:Array<any>;
  countryCodes:Array<any>;
  selectedCode :string = '';
  registerForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { 
    this.vendorType = [
      { value: 'Corporate', title: 'Corporate', label: 'Corporate' }, 
     { value: 'Partner', title: 'Partner', label: 'Partner' },
     { value: 'Company Nomination', title: 'Company Nomination', label: 'Company Nomination' }
   ];
   this.countryCodes = [
     { value: '+1', title: '+1', label: 'USA' }, 
     { value: '+91', title: '+91', label: 'India' }
   ];
  }

  ngOnInit(){


    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      countryCode :["", [Validators.required]],
      category : ["", [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
  registerYourself(){
    var user = this.registerForm.value;
    console.log(user);

  }


}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `</select>` for the `countryCode` control. Aside from that, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Is the `console.log(user)` in `registerYourself` not outputting what you expect?

Comment: there was  must be some type error while posting this article. @MattU i just want value of drop down into my search.component.ts file so that i serve them into my service.ts file, as i am unable to get the value of select from my html file to typescript. can you please help into this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eya69e). You want the initial values to be already selected in the form when component loads. To achieve this you have to set the default values in your formControls. Example:

```
 this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      countryCode :["+1", Validators.required],
      category : ["Corporate", Validators.required]
    });
```

Comment: No sir, unable to get value again :(

Comment: @ManishAgarwal you marked this answer unaccept, are you facing some issues? Let me know I will figure it out for you.

Comment: yes sir, unable to receive the value.

Comment: Can you please explain me more about the issue? In the current stackblitz if you click on signup, values are printing in console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="registerYourself()">
     <select class="wide" id="countrycode" [formControl]="registerForm.get('countryCode')">
         <option *ngFor="let code of countryCodes" [value]="code.value"> 
             {{code.title }}
         </option>
     </select>
     <select class="wide" id="box" [formControl]="registerForm.get('category')">
         <option *ngFor="let cat of vendorType" [value]="cat.value">
              {{ cat.title }}</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
</form>
```